# Does Angular SwPush override Firebase Cloud Messaging sdk method making it obsolete?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is SwPush overriding FCM `.onMessage()` the intended behaviour?

From my experiment, I discovered that `firebase.messaging().onMessage()` and `firebase.messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler()` do not work when used with Angular's SwPush. SwPush is working fine for receiving message.

On a side note, using `firebase.messaging().requestPermission()` works perfectly. This is to prove that firebase.messaging() sdk is working with Angular. However, `.onMessage()` and `.setBackgroundMessageHandler()` of FCM sdk are so far the only two methods not working when used with Angular Service Worker. The rest of the methods are fine.

Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: Did you add FCM SDK related code to your service worker [as explained here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive)?

Comment: yes I did. It's exactly working but as explained I could only use it to request for FCM token. I can't use it to receive messages. However, it works if I use swUpdate to receive messages. It seems to me that it's overriding it. Further investigation is required to confirm this.